# to extract .fic to sql server 2012 using Windev

Tags: sql-server, windev

I have an existing data_base using Windev but i want to convert that database(and extract         all data (file .fic) from windev to sql-server 2012 to use them .
 As an information my application is called Payroll.exe with 4.0.0.1 version.
 which version of Windev must i download to extract my data ?
 what i need in sql-server to do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the version of the dll found with your WinDev application. For example wd170hf.dll is for WinDev 17, WD90HF.DLL is Windev 9.

The easiest way i can think of doing what u want is either using a program called WDMap (It's installed together with WinDev). Export the table to xls/csv and import that one into a sql-server. This by far is not the best or the fastest solution but it will/should work.

Or use the ODBC connector (this one can be downloaded separately if i am not mistaken). But also comes with WinDev installation.

Note on WinDev u can download & install the full version from the site. But u need a dongle to start the IDE. (u can use the tools (like WDMAP) without a dongle. Officially your not allowed to install the IDE if u do not have a dongle. The express version won't allow u to edit source files made with a full version.

Answer (score 0):

Pimmetje answer is a good one, you can also use Hyperfile Control Center which is included in windev to export datas in csv files. Always use the last version with windev, it's compatible with older one.

You can also create a gateway application in windev (if you have a license) which will read in hyperfile files and write to sql server.

You will not be able to do this kinds of things (using WDMap, HF Control Center, gateway application) if files are protected by password. Perhaps you can find it in a side file of payroll.exe.